# Ubuntu 10.04 boot problems

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

When Ubuntu 10.04 boots, it loads, appears to be fine, then transitions to a blank screen. Pressing a key will bring it back, however, it then reverts to my old wallpaper and password protected login protocol. Anyone else have problems?

Comment: considering that Lucid is still alpha software, you probably ought to post this on http://ubuntuforums.org/ or similar.

Answer (score 2):

One helpful tip:  often .files in your home directory will cause updates to act a bit strange.  I'd guess from the question that might be the case - so either move everything from your home directory into a temp. holding location, or create a new user and try logging in with that.

If that does happen to be the issue, you can then gradually restore the various configs to see what might be causing the problem.